# Visual Studio 2012 publish web project vs. MSBuild

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

I added a new Configuration to my MVC app. Visual Studio 2012 added the configuration block to the top of the .csproj. When I then attempt to build the project via msbuild:

`msbuild WebApp.csproj /t:Clean;Build;_WPPCopyWebApplication /p:Configuration=QA;WebProjectOutputDir=c:\builds\webapp\qa`

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'WebApp.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='QA'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [c:\code\WebApp.csproj]`

Does anyone know how I can get new Configurations added *AFTER* the default configuration block? MSBuild works just fine once I move the configuration block down with the other Configurations.

EDIT to show how Visual Studio 2012 adds configurations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

```
<!-- NEW CONFIGURATIONS ARE ADDED HERE -->

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'QA|AnyCPU'">
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- DEFAULT PropertyGroup is here -->

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
<PropertyGroup>
 <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
 <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
 <!-- blah blah -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

`<!-- EXISTING CONFIGURATIONS ARE DOWN HERE -->`
...

Comment: Your question is not clear.  The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: show the details of where you added the block, the clue will be there

Comment: @Ramhound I added an example of the resulting .csproj when you add new configurations.

Comment: Carefully check the spelling of "AnyCPU". I had a situation where in one project, it was "Any CPU".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've seen that as well. However, it's not the case here. If I move the QA configuration block down below the Default, it works fine. It's really an issue of VS2012 adding configurations to the top of the csproj instead of inline with the existing configurations.

Comment: What happens if you also specify the Platform property?

Comment: Good call. That does work. I would still prefer VS2012 to add the new Configuration below the default so I don't have to specify Platform. Who needs an MVC project to be x86 only??

Comment: Deffo try it with \p:Platform="AnyCPU" instead of \p:Platform="Any CPU". That worked form me! Was looking at this for ages!